# Beamer and monochrome-xcolor

Tags: beamer, pdftex, color

When using the `monochrome` option for `xcolor` in a Beamer presentation, the canvas background shows up as entirely black when compiling with `pdflatex`, but would be entirely white if compiled with `xelatex`. (I'm using MacTeX 2015):

```
\documentclass[xcolor={monochrome}]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello World!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What's causing the different behavior? Is there any way to get the background white when using `monochrome`, at least when the canvas background is left as the default?

Comment: Can you try with Adobe Reader if you have it by any chance?

Comment: @percusse I tried opening the pdflatex output with Preview, Skim and Adobe Reader DC (all on Mac OSX El Capitan), the frame is still gloriously black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the default `background canvas` of a beamer presentation is not transparent but filled with the `normal text` background color, as it is defined as

```
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{parent=normal text}
```

in `beamercolorthemedefault.sty`. So what you could do is to actually make it transparent by setting

```
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
```

---

**Edit:**

Or you could use the xcolor option `gray` instead of `monochrome`, which seems to be working the same with pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: Ah thanks -- no idea how I had the impression that it's transparent; I've now edited my question. But this still doesn't quite explain the different behavior between xelatex and pdflatex, right?

Comment: @LianTzeLim You are right it doesn't explain the different behavior. As far as I understand it, xelatex is in the wrong here, as the monochrome option should set all colors to black hence also white. If you want a grayscale output you should use the option `gray`. Also test this example with `xelatex`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{blue}Test
\end{document}` This does also not work as it should.